# PHP sort multidimension array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort a multidimentional array in a particular way.

I have an array like this :

```
Array (
 [551691] => Array (
   [19129287] => Array (
     [value] => cccccc
     [id] => 19129287
     [col] => 1
   )
   [19129288] => Array (
     [value] => bbbbb
     [id] => 19129288
     [col] => 2
   )
 )

 [550141] => Array (
   [19071703] => Array (
     [value] => aaaaa
     [id] => 19071703
     [col] => 1
   )
   [19071706] => Array (
     [value] => ccccc
     [id] => 19071706
     [col] => 2
   )
 )

 [550139] => Array (
   [19071675] => Array (
     [value] => bbbbb
     [id] => 19071675
     [col] => 1
   )
   [19071676] => Array (
     [value] => ddddd
     [id] => 19071676
     [col] => 2
   )
)
)
```

I would like sort this array by [value] for specific [col]

For exemple for [col] has value 1 :

The first level array with key 550141 should be moved to the first position because the value in the array with [col] => 1 is "aaaaa"

```
Array (

 [550141] => Array ( // <= Moved at first position "value" for col 1 is aaaa
   [19071703] => Array (
     [value] => aaaaa
     [id] => 19071703
     [col] => 1
   )
   [19071706] => Array (
     [value] => ccccc
     [id] => 19071706
     [col] => 2
   )
 )

 [550139] => Array ( // <= Moved at second position
   [19071675] => Array (
     [value] => bbbbb
     [id] => 19071675
     [col] => 1
   )
   [19071676] => Array (
     [value] => ddddd
     [id] => 19071676
     [col] => 2
   )
)

 [551691] => Array (
   [19129287] => Array (
     [value] => cccccc
     [id] => 19129287
     [col] => 1
   )
   [19129288] => Array (
     [value] => bbbbb
     [id] => 19129288
     [col] => 2
   )
 )
)
```

If anybody have a good idea.. :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I found a solution. I don't know if is the best way, but it work :

```
$sortarray = array();

foreach ($datas as $datas_key => $s) {
    foreach ($s as $itemId => $item) {
        if ($item['col'] == 2) {
            $sortarray[] = array(
                'sid' => $datas_key,
                'value' => $item['value']
            );
        }
    }
}

usort($sortarray, function($a,$b) {
    return ($a['value']<$b['value'])?-1:1;
});

$datas_sorted = array();
foreach ($sortarray as $new_sort) {
    $datas_sorted[$new_sort['sid']] = $datas[$new_sort['sid']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own sorting function using http://php.net/usort

You would probably need something like

```
usort($array, function($a,$b) {
  return ($a['value']<$b['value'])?1:-1;
});
```

Obviously you need to adjust it to suit your case, and possibly put it into for {} loop, because you are actually sorting the subarrays.

Comment: Thank for you response. I have tried this, but it order only the last level arrays..

Comment: Well the response is only a clue to get you pointed in right direction. A full solution is a little more complex than that, but isn't it a challenge to try and look it up yourself? TIP: it's a combination of foreach() {}, array_keys() and usort().